# Return only one property from an object

Tags: javascript, variables, methods

```js
const colors = [{id: 1, color: "yellow", picked: true}, {id: 2, color: "green", picked: false}, {id: 3, color: "red", picked: false}];

const pickedColor = colors.find(color => color.picked)
console.log(pickedColor)
```

This snippet returns an object where picked color is located, in this case it's "yellow". However I need to get this value to be stored in `const pickedColor`  instead of having an entire object there. I know I can create another varibale and access it with dot notation, like `const finalColor = pickedColor.color;` but is there a way to return just "yellow" directly into `const pickedColor`?.

Comment: You can access it directly after find: `colors.find(...).color`, or use [optional chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62359000/5648954) if the object might not be found:  `colors.find(...)?.color`

Answer (score 0):

Just access the property of the object that you wish to retrieve. Also, naming your variables more specifically can help to understand what your code does.

```js
const colorObjects = [{id: 1, color: "yellow", picked: true}, {id: 2, color: "green", picked: false}, {id: 3, color: "red", picked: false}];

const pickedColorObject = colorObjects.find(color => color.picked)
console.log(pickedColorObject.color)
```